# SSI - test if a file exists

Tags: html, if-statement, ssi

I'm dynamically adding ssi includes based on variables and I would like to be able to have a default include in case a file doesn't exist. ie:

```
if /file/testthisfile.ssi exists
    add /file/testthisfile.ssi
else
    add /file/default.ssi
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - I was afraid of that answer. But for anyone who might come across this question in the future I did find a work around for simple cases. You can edit the error message and in my case, output an image:

```
<!--#config errmsg="<img src='/file/testthisfile.jpg' alt='' />" -->
```

So if the file doesn't exist you can set a default.

Must underline that this will only work for simple cases, but it's a nice little work around!

Comment: I used  <!--#config errmsg=" " --> before an inlcude.

Answer (score 3):

Actually contrary to the answers here, SSI does in fact support file existence tests. this is the syntax

```
<!--#if expr="-A /private" -->
  Click <a href="/private">here</a> to access private information.
<!--#endif -->
```

Support for the -A flag may need to be enabled in your apache configuration.

The expressions used in this spot of SSI have been factored out into an apache expressions module documented here

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html

but the -A flag is also available in "legacy" SSI expression parsers.

Comment: Here's a link to the v2.2 configuration variable documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_include.html#ssienableaccess
If I edit that from "2.2" to "current" I find it seems to have gone away, however. Is it... superseded? No longer supported? (It's apparently not moot; this doesn't work with my server's default config.)

Comment: "-A" does not test for existence, only whether the URL would be accessible (not forbidden) if it did exist.  Also note that while the v2.2 documentation says "SSIEnableAccess", at least v2.2.24 does not recognize that as a valid directive.  "SSIAccessEnable" appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

SSI does not support file detection.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this for a while, and indeed, ahgood was correct, SSI does not have a built-in file detection function, so flow control is limited.

As an aside, I did find a reference to an extended version of SSI (a VMS based system)

http://wasd.vsm.com.au/doc/env/env_0400.html

and there were some extensions that would allow you to check for file existence in some sort of a fashion.

However, more often then not, if one were using SSI, one would probably be running in a LAMP environment, so one could take advantage of SSI's ability to run a CGI/PHP script in the include statement.

Without too much trouble, one could resort to:

```
<body> 
<!--#include virtual="insert_intro.html" -->
<h2>Insert An Existing File</h2>
<!--#include 
virtual='checkFileExists.php?fn=insert_help.html&df=insert_default.html' -->
<h2>Insert a Non-Existing File</h2>
<!--#include 
virtual='checkFileExists.php?fn=insert_no_help.html&df=insert_default.html' -->
</body>
```

which uses a PHP script to do all the file checking:

```
<?php
$theFileName = $_GET['fn'];
$theDefault  = $_GET['df'];
if ( file_exists($theFileName) === TRUE ) {
    include($theFileName);
} else {
    include($theDefault);
}
?>
```

I pass two file names, the intended file and the backup/default file, the script checks for the first and if it is not found, uses the second.

This approach begs the question, why use SSI when PHP is available?  In some cases, especially in a legacy system, there may be a big website based on SSI and a work-around, though less elegant, would solve a problem.

PHP is not mandatory, a PERL script would also work.

Finally, I did experiment with trying to use PHP's `apache_setenv` but I could not figure out how to pass environment variables between PHP, Apache and SSI (I also tried setting $_SERVER and $_ENV variables but without success).

Comment: That's not SSI solution, if we can use php instead, then the problem will be resolved easily. =)

Comment: Very true indeed... I still thought the hybrid solution was worth mentioning.

Comment: This approach would also introduce SERIOUS security problems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Apache 2.4 you can use the -F option (note the quoting).

```
<!--#if expr='-F "/private"' -->
  Click <a href="/private">here</a> to access private information.
<!--#endif -->
```

From the docs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html):

> True if string is a valid file, accessible via all the server's
>   currently-configured access controls for that path. This uses an
>   internal subrequest to do the check, so use it with care - it can
>   impact your server's performance!

For the example to work the Apache user will need access to the direcotory/flag that you are testing. You may also need the following in a .htaccess or httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory /private>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, like this:

```
<!--#include virtual="/file/testthisfile.ssi" onerror="/file/default.ssi" -->
```

Please note that "-F" unary operator, as well as "-A" unary operator, only refer to path accessibility and not to actual existence of the resource.

Have a look here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html (Unary operators).

Operators performing such task (-e, -s, -f) are not available under mod_include.